# Linux- error while running executable files

Tags: linux, executable, hadoop

I am trying to run an executable file on newly installed Ubuntu and I am getting the following error:

>./hadoop

```
hadoop : Not a directoryh
```

>hadoop

```
hadoop command not found
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: The second error message means hadoop can't be found in your path. The first seem returned by hadoop. Maybe you could add the hadoop tag to attract hadoop users and give more details about what you are doing.

Comment: hadoop is present in the path. and i am running these commands from the directory where hadoop executable is lying

Comment: could you post `ls -l hadoop` output.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu you can try pre-packaged Cloudera's distribution. Works very well for me.
Add repositories for your version of Ubuntu, create user 'hadoop' (no root required to access configuration files)

Answer (score 0):

This answer very conditional, but it might be the problem.

If you're running this on a 64-bit ubuntu, you're OS might not have the 32-bit linker libraries. To install them, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

If it was the problem, it should work.

Answer (score -2):

You need to make it executable first

```
chmod 777 ./hadoop
./hadoop
```

Comment: This is overkill. You are giving everyone the rights to read, write and execute the file. And it looks like the user already has execution rights here.

Comment: I doubt he's working on a critical system, but for better security you could try another combination. In fact the best would be to read on up chmod and decide what best fits your needs.

Comment: I have tried chmod, it doesnot work.
chmod 777 is not an issue for me as i am running this on a single node is pesudo-distributed mode.